# RichTextFX line numbers column extended for entire text area

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

Could someone tell me how to implement RichTextFX CodeArea with line numbers section extended till the end of the area?
This is how it looks like now:

[image: textareafx sample]

I don't need line numbers after line 12 but I would like to see this grey bar to fill the entire text area.
Something like here:

[image: expected ui]

P.S. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Dragonthoughts well, the problem is that I don't know where to start because I don't know if something like that is even supported by RichTextFX. I could just create new javafx element outside RichTextFX but thats plan b.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rather old question, but since I had the same problem, let me share the solution I came up with.

What I did is to smuggle in a rectangle and make sure it is the bottom-most element (i.e. basically part of the background).  However, there are a few gotchas when doing this, because the underlying `CodeArea` is not aware of our new node.  If you just insert the rectangle, it might get removed when the `CodeArea` decides to rebuild the nodes.  And getting the right width is a bit tricky because the width of line numbers can basically change at any time and the line-number labels themselves fade in and out of existence whenever you scroll.

So, in order to address these issues, my code sits in the `layoutChildren()` method and is thus called whenever the nodes in the editor have changed.  First we check that the rectangle is actually there as the bottom-most node or insert it if missing.  Second, we set the width of the rectangle to the width of the first visible line-number label (which might fail if there are no paragraphs at the moment).

The code itself here is in *Scala*, but probably easy enough to be quickly adapted to *Java*.

```scala
class MyCodeArea extends CodeArea {

  protected val gutterRect = new Rectangle()
  gutterRect.heightProperty.bind(this.heightProperty)
  gutterRect.getStyleClass.add("lineno")

  override protected def layoutChildren(): Unit = {
    try {
      val children = getChildren
      if (!(children.get(0) eq gutterRect))
        children.add(0, gutterRect)
      val index = visibleParToAllParIndex(0)
      val wd = getParagraphGraphic(index).prefWidth(-1)
      gutterRect.setWidth(wd)
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable =>
    }
    super.layoutChildren()
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the colour of the rectangle must be assimilated manually.  The reason is that the `Label`s used for line numbers use `-fx-background-color`, whereas the `Rectangle` uses `-fx-fill`.  Hence, just setting the same CSS class `"lineno"` (as I did in my code above) does little to get the colour right.  But it allowed me to put both into the same CSS class and therefore have one place where I can change it:

```
.lineno {
    -fx-fill: ivory;  // or whatever colour you like
    -fx-background-color: -fx-fill;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to solve my problem but I eventually replaced RichTextFX with WebView +  Ace editor (mainly for performance reasons).